# Is there a difference between "newest" and "creation"?

Tags: discussion, api, sort

When I look at some API endpoints, say `/questions/tagged/{tags}` and `/questions/{id}`, I see that the former can be sorted by `newest`, and the latter can be sorted by `creation`, both ascending or descending.

Am I correct in thinking that sorting by `newest` `ascending` is the same thing as sorting by `creation` `descending`?

If that's true, why do they have different names?  If it's not, what do they mean?

Comment: `/questions/tagged/{tags}` can't be sorted ascending.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is historical (and should probably be updated..., hmm).

`/questions` is/was a window onto https://stackoverflow.com/questions ; notice that there sorting is by `newest`.

Accordingly, sorts for `/questions` were once fixed and didn't support `min`, `max`, or `order`.